# Can GetPreSignedUrlRequest with only a partial key?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using GetPreSignedUrlRequest to get a URL from S3. Everything is working how I would like except I don't always know the full name of the file I need the link for.

For example I might know "FileName" but the full file name in S3 is "FileName.txt".

My question is: Is there a way to use a partial key when creating the request?

```
GetPreSignedUrlRequest preSignedUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = fileName,
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(int.Parse(expiryInMinutes))
                };
```

I would like a way to use the above code with a partial key.

Comment: It is not possible, the presigned must be for a specific key. you can't even do it for the bucket itself, it must be for an object inside it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll look for a different way to do this

Comment: But you can list the keys of the bucket and generate a presigned for each one you need.